# Tag synonym request [tag:xbox-live-profile] ↔ [tag:gamertag]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I'd like to make a tag synonym request [xbox-live-profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-live-profile) and [gamertag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamertag). I don't know which should be merged into which though, so I would like to open that to discussion.

Background: "Gamertag" is MicrosoftSpeak for an Xbox Live user profile. So do we go with the more explanatory one or the official name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch. Now both tags point to [xbox-gamertag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-gamertag).

(I added the xbox- prefix to [gamertag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamertag) for consistency with other subtags such as [minecraft-redstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-redstone).)

Comment: I'm thinking it should be [tag:xbox-live-gamertag], but eh. They're sorted out.